# Variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, json, database-connection

I try to make an application and this application have a login page were i want to chech if the user exist in database , i have try to implement the prepared statement but i have a error comming up , but my code sounds ok i only check for is name .

This is the error

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/nicetaxi/public_html/mobilapp/getdata.php on line 16
> [05-Nov-2021 06:31:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/nicetaxi/public_html/mobilapp/getdata.php on line 21

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "databasename";

//Here we will get name entered by the user from the key 'name'
$name = $_POST["name"];
//This will contain a JSON array of your data.

$result_array = array();
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='$name'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($result_array, $row);
    echo $row['name'];
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($result_array, $row);
        }
    }
/*This sends a JSON encded array to client */
echo json_encode($result_array);
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prepared statement seems incorrect there

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='$name'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
```

The above should be

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
```

please check the example [example prepared staement](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score -1):

In Fact it was a distraction of me on a missing line
//This will contain a JSON array of your data.

```
$result_array = array();
```